# Weblogic not starting as Datasource is down

Tags: weblogic, middleware

Weblogic not starting as Datasource is down. It shows error invalid username password. How can I change or remove faulty Data source when weblogic is down

Comment: Can you show the error message? (Censor company names etc.). I am not sure if misconfigured or offline datasource is able prevent the WL from starting. Btw I deleted my wrong answer, since it did not help.

Comment: Error shown was invalid username and password.. But using same username and password I was able to ping using WLST dbping command. Is there a way I can start weblogic without datasource by configuring it from WLST . Else I need to recreate admin server

Comment: Sure, weblogic doesn't need a datasource to work. Just remove the datasource configuration from wls12\user_projects\domains\mydomain\config\config.xml file (and the corresponding file in the jdbc folder next to it). That's all the references weblogic has for a datasource

Comment: Oh. I don't know how you can remove it with wlst since I don't use it. sorry

Comment: Thanks Alot.. this helped

Answer (score 0):

you can also start your server with the property -Dweblogic.deployment.IgnorePrepareStateFailures=true
This prevents the server to start in ADMIN mode when it is not able to create a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to cd $MW_HOME_STANDALONE/user_projects/domains//config/jdbc/
2. Run sed -i 's///g' *.*